# Explanation of the six temperaments

Tags: theravada, karma, meditation-insight, samadhi

Greedy, hating, deluded, faithful, intelligent, speculative

I know they may seem self exploratory on the surface, but I'm looking for an understanding to more properly determine how one is to know which one he/she is someone else is.

Comment: on the six [Carita (Nature, CharacterOr Habitual Conduct)](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/lib/authors/janakabhivamsa/abhidhamma_in_daily_life#carita_nature_characteror_habitual_conduct)

Comment: "A moha dominant person is generally idle, confused and deluded. He cannot differentiate vice from virtue and right from wrong. He lacks of power of judgment and is void of sati and paññā. As for vitakka person he is incapable of doing moral deeds being very lazy. He talks away his precious times and does nothing substantial."...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important topics in Buddhism is the lack of basis for "identity view". This comes out, for example, in [MN62](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato):

> “Rāhula, you should truly see any kind of form at all—past, future, or present; internal or external; coarse or fine; inferior or superior; far or near: *all* form—with right understanding: **‘This is not mine, I am not this, this is not my self.’**”

Having faith that identity view is baseless, one is led to conclude that those who cling to identity view are often:

- **Greedy**, which can be recognized in the unfairness and suffering of those excluded from shared resources such as drinking water during a drought.
- **Hating**, which can be recognized in a lack of compassion for others such as saying "steerage passengers will have no lifeboats."
- **Deluded**, which can be recognized in a never-ending grasping at the vanities of health, youth, and life.

Yet those who have identity view can also be:

- **Faithful**, which can be recognized in a willingness to experience the fruit of teachings of the Buddha personally
- **Intelligent**, which can be recognized in a discernment between skillful qualities and unskillful qualities
- **Speculative**, which can be recognized in a struggle to understand the meaning and worth of the teachings of the Buddha such as "*This is not mine, I am not this, this is not my self,’"*

Comment: Is this householders opinion, view?